# How can I install zombodb elasticsearch plugin?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, plugins, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I install elasticsearch5.0.0 and I want to add zdb extension but when i run `sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install zombodb` . It has error : ERROR: Unknown plugin zombodb. So how can i install this plugin ? I need this plugin . thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1):

You need to download appropriate ZomboDB plugin from [here](https://www.zombodb.com/releases/) 
, and run command `sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:///path/to/zombodb-es-plugin.zip`